# How to remove a word declared in a variable in .csv file with python?

Tags: python, regex, string, csv

Dear all developers and friends,

The code is here:
http://argo1chem.blogspot.gr/

I have created the following file `output1.csv` where one of its part is depicted:

```
D13,93.49902,103.49902,113.49902,123.49902,133.49902
D13,143.49902,153.49902,163.49902,173.49902,183.49902
D13,193.49902,203.49902,213.49902,223.49902,233.49902
```

And I would like to remove the D13, word and transform it to the following:

```
93.49902,103.49902,113.49902,123.49902,133.49902  
143.49902,153.49902,163.49902,173.49902,183.49902  
193.49902,203.49902,213.49902,223.49902,233.49902
```

Initially the user types as input the D13 word which is stored in `var1`:

```
print "Enter %d dihedral angle:"  %i  
i = i+1  
var1 = raw_input(' ')  
print(var1)
```

Therefore, I would like to remove the word D13 from the `.csv` file utilizing the `var1` variable.

So far I have seen that in general it is used

```
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
```

Where old in our case should be the word D13.

However, since I have many variables and each time their name changes I would like to be fully automatic instead of modifying the script with the selected name.

For example for D23 I should use and this is not what I need:

```
S.replace(D23, new[, count]) -> string
```

I would like instead of a word to be typed, to be replaced by the variable for example I mean:

```
S.replace((var1), new[, count]) -> string    var1 is D13   
S.replace((var2), new[, count]) -> string    var2 is D26
```

Since the above code is not suitable could you suggest me a solution for my case?

Comment: Please from now on indent code by `4` spaces, or surround it with backticks like so, `\`this.is['my'].code()\``

Comment: I am not sure what you actually need - checking if a string has some user input substring at the start and if yes, remove it with `replace`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/CSRADu). (I do not know where the comma after `D13` comes in, so I used the `.format`)

Comment: yes that exactly. I want to remove the word D13 in the above file. It was initially typed by the user as input and was used in order to receive the first file. Now, in the second we want it removed. What is your opinion?

Comment: I do not understand how you know which substring in the old file is user input (if your input data is an "old" file inly). If you have a list of the user input values, you can try reading the old file line by line, and remove the substrings from the start of the lines.

Comment: inputfile = open('output1.csv', 'r')
outputfile = open('output1_f.csv', 'a')
for line in inputfile:
    line = line.replace('         ',',')
    line = line.replace('        ',',')
    line = line.replace('       ',',')
    line = line.replace('      ',',')
    line = line.replace('     ',',')
    line = line.replace('    ',',')
    line = line.replace('   ',',')
    line = line.replace('  ',',')
    line = line.replace(' ',',')
    line = line.replace('-',',-')
    line = line.replace(',,',',')
    line = line.replace('D13,','')
    outputfile.write(line)
inputfile.close()
outputfile.close()

Comment: that was the original code where D13 should be replaced by the variable var1 given as input by the user. Excuse me for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You are mixing variables with string literals, the code "S.replace(D23, new[, count])" does not make sense, D23 is content, not a variable name. You want to replace "D23" by providing "D23" on some variable, set by the application, or by the user.

Comment: exactly Pinto! do you agree with Wiktor that startswith should be used or do you have another proposal?

Comment: @ManolisSemidalas: Your question is unclear: do you know the substrings to remove? How are they represented in the code? Since they are at the start, you do not even need a regex as you see. Please update the question with the code you have.

Comment: http://argo1chem.blogspot.gr/  or can be downloaded from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/argo1/

Comment: thank you very much for your time

Comment: Replace the `if line.startswith(D13):  line.replace("{},".format(var1), "", 1)` with `if line.startswith(var1):  line = line.replace("{},".format(var1), "", 1)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for your help!

Comment: It works very well! If you are interested you can contribute in this project. Every help is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to remove the initial field, whatever it is, `str.split` could be enough:

```
for line in inputfile:
    outputfile.write(line.split(',', 1)[1])  # split(..., 1) only splits once!
```

If you need to control the value of first field, you just take both values of the split

```
for line in inputfile:
    field, end_of_line.split(',', 1) # head <= D13 (or whatever)
    # your processing
    ....
```

But if you want to make some cleanup (remove unwanted spaces, reorder fields, etc.), you really should use the `csv` module:

```
import csv
...
rd = csv.reader(inputfile)
wr = csv.writer(outputfile)
for row in rd:                       # split each line into a list of fields
    row = [ x.strip() for x in row ] # remove spaces around  fields
    outrow = row[1:]                 # of whatever builds the output row
    wr.writerow(outrow)
```

Comment: It works perfect! I have another question in order to remove unwanted space I utilized the following: for line in inputfile: line = line.replace(' ', '') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',') line = line.replace(' ',',')  line = line.replace(' ',',') So in your opinion would be more efficient to utilize the x.strip module?  Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @ManolisSemidalas: the `str.strip` method ensures that you remove unwanted spaces (at the begin or end of a field), and will never touch to spaces that could be included in text fields